# Getting expression values breaks when class is in other projects

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-expressions

I've written some code that takes an `Expression` and acts as a proxy to make certain calls. The main bit of code that makes this work is such

```
private static IEnumerable<object> GetArguments(MethodCallExpression body)
{
    IEnumerable<object> arguments =
        body.Arguments.Select(
            expression =>
            {
                MemberExpression member = expression as MemberExpression;
                return ((dynamic) member.Member).GetValue(((ConstantExpression) member.Expression).Value);
            });

    return arguments;
}
```

This gets the values of the parameters present in the `Expression` and returns them in an `IEnumerable`. That's the behavior I get when I wrote this in the initially consuming project and I can see the resulting argument values being output correctly. I even moved this to a test bed project to test the code and it worked fine there as well.  However, when I put the .cs files in another project, updating the namespaces, and reference it to be able to use it widely, I get exceptions such as

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.PropertyExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression'.

and I can't even use my application.

I've rolled my extraction back to the "it works locally" state to ensure it, in fact, worked, and it did. However, I have noticed I still get some exceptions in my logging even though it didn't throw up on me like it does when it's external to the project. I can still use my application in spite of this.

Repeating the move to an external project and using it by way of a reference reintroduces those errors and I can't even use my app.

New question: how do I handle `PropertyExpression`s? They don't expose a `Value` property and are internal so I there's no cast and check. `MemberExpression` also doesn't have a `Value` property.

Comment: The exception depends on which `MethodCallExpression` do you pass.

Comment: Apparently some of the arguments are not `ConstantExpression`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be not to rely on the shape of the expressions at all and let the Expression Tree library evaluate each subexpression for you by building a `LambdaExpression` and then using [`Compile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345362) on it and executing the returned delegate:

```
private static IEnumerable<object> GetArguments(MethodCallExpression body)
{
    return body.Arguments.Select(
        expression => Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(
            Expression.Convert(expression, typeof(object))).Compile()());
}
```

Note that compiling each subexpression will take some time, so this approach is going to be relatively slow.

Comment: This could be combined with the approach in the question as an optimisation for the paths where it can work, casting with `as` rather than `()` and choosing the approach based on whether that returns null or not.

Answer (score 0):

You should evaluate the expression and not rely on it's shape. The easiest way is to call `.Compile().Invoke()`, but that is slow and creates a memory-leak. You can avoid that by *interpreting* the expression (stepping recursively through it with a visitor and perform the operations in it manually) or cache your compilation result. I wrote a library that can do both, is fast and used in production for quite some time now: https://github.com/Miaplaza/expression-utils